# How do I determine from the documentation what type of exception a function can throw?

Tags: c++, exception

I am new to C++ programming but have programmed in higher-level languages to find my way around most documentation. I'm learning about exception handling in C++, specifically with this example:

```
vector<int> myNums;

try
{
    myNums.resize(myNums.max_size() + 1);
}
catch (const bad_alloc& err)
{
    cout << err.what() << endl;
}
```

This code doesn't catch the exception because the exception thrown by the .resize() method isn't `bad_alloc`; it's a `length_error`. So, from this documentation, how do you get to that? Maybe I missed something obvious.

https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

The only specific exception mentioned in there is `bad_alloc`. Can someone walk me through how you'd get to know that `length_error` is the right exception starting from that page?

Comment: It is interesting.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error clearly says "This exception is thrown by member functions of std::basic_string and std::vector::reserve" but you called std::vector::resize so even reading that page wouldn't give you the hint you are after.

Comment: See also [try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) and the catch-all clause `catch (...)` that matches any exception. (hint: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) is the C++ reference to use)

Comment: I've updated cppreference on vector::resize - it's a public wiki and this is how it improves

Comment: This kind of thing is why languages need to integrate possible error return values using their type system, so it can be completely automatic & exhaustively statically-checked.

Comment: @iono: Yeah, everybody loves Java's checked exceptions. ;-)

Comment: @Heinzi Java is probably the worst programming language ever designed; of course it's going to get even perfectly good ideas as wrong as possible

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not uncommon. The complexity of the language has increased so much over the years, accumulating multiple revisions to the C++ standard, that even the C++ standard itself can be at odds with itself, sometimes.

Let's just see what the C++ standard itself says about two versions of the overloaded `resize()` vector method. I happen to have a copy of N4860 handy which is, basically, the C++20 version, and while looking up what the C++ standard itself says about `resize()`'s exceptions, I found that the two `resize()` overloads define their exception behavior as follows:

> constexpr void resize(size_type sz);
>
> // ...
>
> Remarks: If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor
> of a non-Cpp17CopyInsertable T there are no effects.
>
> // ...
>
> constexpr void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
>
> // ...
>
> Remarks: If an exception is thrown there are no effects.

That's the only mention of exceptions in `resize()`. I found nothing on a more general in `vector` itself, nor in "Container Requirements", there was some discussion of exception guarantees but none pertaining to the specific details of vector's `resize()` or `reserve()`.

This is an obvious oversight. It's fairly obvious that when it comes to exceptions that might be generated as a result of reallocations, both overloads should have the same exception behavior. The first overload's description is lifted straight from `reserve()` that just precedes it. It goes without saying that `resize()` uses `reserve()` to grow the vector's capacity, when needed, and inherits its exception guarantees/behavior.

But the same thing must be true with the 2nd `resize()` overload. The only difference between them is that one default-constructs new values when the vector grows and the other one copy-constructs. But in terms of exception behavior during reallocation they must be identical. The total overall difference, related to exceptions, between the two overloads is due to any exception differences between the value's default constructor and/or its copy/move constructors.

> My question is, from looking at this documentation, how do you get to that? > Maybe I missed something obvious.

No, you did not miss anything. The C++ standard itself has some gaps; not to mention 2nd-hand sources of documentation like the one you're looking at.

You get where you want to go by studying everything about the class, template, or algorithm in question, understanding how it must work -- i.e. the `resize()`s inheriting certain parts of their behavior from `reserve()` -- and then drawing the inescapable inferences.

TLDR: it is what it is.

Comment: An answer only experience can teach...

Comment: I don't think "it goes without saying" that `resize` calls `reserve`. Here reserve+resize and plain resize do different things: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434b5e92dff1575f  

They do, of course, share code, since both may have to reallocate the vector which falls through to allocator_traits::allocate (which is where bad_alloc is specified).

As far as spec, since `resize`s don't have an explicit Throws: clause, they can throw [any exception](https://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#res.on.exception.handling-4.sentence-1)

Answer (score 8):

Starting with https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/, if you've got a case like yours pushing `max_size()`, you might pay special attention to the case listed on this doc page which states:

> If n is also greater than the current container capacity, an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space takes place.

Since your case is absolutely going to be greater than the current container capacity, this might be worth looking into. Linked in this chunk of text is the doc page for capacity: https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/. From the capacity page, you would read that `vector::reserve` is used for explicitly increasing the capacity of the vector. Since your case with `max_size() + 1` is certainly going to involve increasing vector capacity, you might suspect this function is involved. So you might go to the doc page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Here you would read that `vector::reserve` takes a parameter `new_cap` which determines the new capacity of a vector. It throws `length_error` when `new_cap > max_size()`.

I give this series of steps not because I think anyone would/should be expected to dig this much through docs every time they write code. Only because you were curious what steps might have led you to the exception that was thrown.

I agree it would be much better if the documentation for `resize` just covered all it's bases with regards to which exceptions get thrown in all cases. Unfortunately, this is all too common with regards to documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You need to dig a bit to track it down.

I'm going to use documentation at cppreference, which does a reasonably decent job of tracking what happens in the standards.  (The standards are the authoritative source, but the standards have evolved over time).

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector, the second template argument when instantiating a vector is an allocator type, which defaults to `std::allocator<T>` (where `T` is the vector's element type).

Because the allocator is defaulted, it is not often referred to explicitly in user code (most developers do not need to use a non-default allocator).

But

```
std::vector<int> myNums;
```

is actually equivalent to

```
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > myNums;
```

The specification of a `vector`s `resize()` member function describes what happens when it throws, but not the circumstances in which it will throw - or what it may throw.

Memory allocation for `std::vector` is actually handled by its `reserve()` member function. Documentation for that function at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve states it throws `std::length_error` if `new_cap > max_size()`, or any exception thrown by `Allocator::allocate()` (typically `std::bad_alloc`).   `Allocator` is the name of the second template parameter mentioned above.

That is a hint, but we can get even more specific by digging into documentation for the default allocator at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator and for its `allocate()` member function at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate which reveals that function will throw `std::bad_alloc` if allocation fails.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than read through documentation or code to find an answer that may not be correct, I think the best option is to do something you should be doing anyway: write a test.

If your thoroughly test your code, the exceptions it throws will become naturally apparent and you can handle them.